# How to show html in file in react-pdf component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf, pdf-reader, react-pdf

```
    import sample from './response.pdf'
```

React-pdf Component.

```
<Document
    file={sample}
     onLoadSuccess={this.onDocumentLoad} >
    <Page pageNumber={pageNumber} />
 </Document>
```

I am using manual PDF in the document component. So its working fine 
Is there any way to show Html file in file key.
example: I have a html like this

sample1=Html code etc ...

```
<Document
    file={sample1}
     onLoadSuccess={this.onDocumentLoad} >
    <Page pageNumber={pageNumber} />
 </Document>
```

This I tried, Can anyone guide be how to use this.

Comment: This html code you want to display as an image? Or do you want to run this code?

Comment: yess, want to see  as a pdf viewer

Comment: i am storinh html in one variable sample1, I need to show that html in PDF viewer

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. You want to see the code as text?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a PDF viewer that takes whole file as a parameter and displays it to you.

To convert an HTML string/file to PDF you would need another package that uses string content as stream and converts it for you.

You can have a look at this package available 
[html-to-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-pdf/%22html-to-pdf%22)

**Usage**

```
var htmlToPdf = require('html-to-pdf');
var html = ...; //Some HTML String from code above

htmlToPdf.convertHTMLString(html, 'path/to/destination.pdf',
    function (error, success) {
        if (error) {
            console.log('Oh noes! Errorz!');
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            console.log('Woot! Success!');
            console.log(success);
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: i want to save it in same path
htmlToPdf.convertHTMLString(html, './previewpage.pdf',

Will it save in the same  path only

Comment: yes it will save in same path if you do this `./previewpage.pdf`

Comment: you need to implement this method in backend of node. I suppose you are trying it in component file?

Comment: that is wrong. This should be happening at server itself. Basically, A browser don't convert streams to file for security purposes. You will need to pass your html content to backend via some function in your component that will get you file written on desired location.